# Unknown class _TtC3_6514ViewController in Interface Builder file.というエラーが出ます。

Tags: swift, xcode, spritekit

Swift Docs のサイトにある　「[016 タッチした座標にNodeを移動させる](https://sites.google.com/a/gclue.jp/swift-docs/ni-yinki100-ios/spritekit/tatchishita-zuo-biaoninodewo-yi-dongsaseru)」をコピペして実行すると、Unknown class _TtC3_6514ViewController in Interface Builder file.というエラーが出ます。
因みに、_TtC3_というクラスはコード上にはありません。
Swift Dock内にある他のサンプルをコピペしても同じエラーが出ます。
ググってみても明確な答えにはたどり着けません。
どなたか解る方、お教えください。
お願いします。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 016 タッチした座標にNodeを移動させる

ということは、その前に15ステップの教習があるのですね？15ステップすべての課題をクリアできていましたか？おそらくできてないと思います。特に最初のステップ「000 GameViewControllerの設定をする」の課題ができていないと、この課題もできないような、教習の作りになっているようです。

Xcodeで、Main.storyboardを開いてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`ViewController`を選択します。（おそらく上図のような`Game View Controller`という名称になっていないと思います。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

*Identity Inspector*を開いて、クラス名を`GameViewController`に切り替えます。

これで、エラーなしでプログラムが動くかわかりませんが、すくなくとも「Unknown class _TtC3_6514ViewController in Interface Builder file.」というエラーが出なくなるはずです。

繰り返しますが、こう教習型は、地道に最初の課題からひとつひとつ順番にクリアしていってください。

Comment: お礼が遅くなってすみませんでした。
無事解決いたしました。
ありがとうございました。